# how do i return a count of match items

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I have a sorted generic list. I would like to return the first 10 that match a condition.

sort of like the method below but only the first 10 items

```
  mySortedlist.FindAll(delegate(myclass tmp){ return tmp.ID == 123;});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
int count = 0;
mySortedlist.FindAll(delegate(myclass tmp){ return (tmp.ID == 123 && ++count <= 10);});
```

Comment: +1, have to love delegate scope. ;-) (And, not to be picky, `delegate(){}` needs to be spell-checked. ;-)

Comment: +1 - Nice - but for a fresh mind it would raise more question than it's answering.

Comment: @Brad Haha, I just copy-pasted his delegate, I'll change it now!

Comment: Personally I would try to avoid using side-effects in a predicate like this. It makes it easy to mess up in unexpected ways.

Answer (score 6):

Well, that will return a list already. You can create your own equivalent of `Enumerable.Take` pretty easily:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Take<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int size)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        count++;
        if (count == size)
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
List<myclass> filtered =  mySortedlist.FindAll(delagate(myclass tmp) {
     return tmp.ID == 123;
});
List<myclass> list = new List<myclass>(Helper.Take(filtered, 10));
```

Another option is to use [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/) so that you can use LINQ as much as possible - ideally using C# 3 even when you're targeting .NET 2.0, if possible. It'll make your life much simpler :)